# Delete specific item clicking icon React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I´m trying to do an exercise in React JS "To Do List"
I have to delete some task clicking the trash button, but I don´t know how to do it, because with my code it is deleting all the task.
Could someone help me and explaining me step by step how to do it? I am a programming  begginer student

Here is my code

```js
import React from "react";

//include bootstrap npm library into the bundle
import "bootstrap";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

//create your first component
export class InputToDo extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   input: "",
   messages: []
  };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.keyPressed = this.keyPressed.bind(this);
  this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
 }

 handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
 }

 keyPressed(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target.value !== "") {
   this.submitMessage();
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 }

 submitMessage() {
  this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input] });
  this.setState({ input: "" });
 }

 deleteTask() {
  this.setState({ messages: [] });
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="container">
    <h2 className="title">
     To Do List
     <i className="fas fa-tasks" />
    </h2>
    <input
     className="divInput"
     placeholder="What´s next to be done?"
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     onKeyPress={this.keyPressed}
     value={this.state.input}
    />
    <ul className="list-group">
     {this.state.messages.map((item, i) => (
      <li className="list-group-item d-flex" key={i}>
       {item}
       <i
        onClick={this.deleteTask}
        className="far fa-trash-alt ml-auto"
       />
      </li>
     ))}
    </ul>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

.main {
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 2px rgb(80, 75, 75);
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background-color: rgba(230, 255, 253, 0.987);
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


.fas {
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.divInput {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-right: 1.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;   
}

.list-group-item {
    width: 360px;
}


.far {
    color:red;
    align-content: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
//import react into the bundle
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

//include bootstrap npm library into the bundle
import "bootstrap";

//include your index.scss file into the bundle
import "../styles/index.scss";

//import your own components
import { InputToDo } from "./component/InputToDo.js";

//render your react application
ReactDOM.render(<InputToDo />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Inside Delete function, you are removing all tasks, instead you should remove an element from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to pass the index of the element in the deleteTask function call:

```js
<i
  onClick={() => this.deleteTask(i)}
  className="far fa-trash-alt ml-auto"
/>
```

Then you can remove the item from the state with the deleteTask function as follows:

```js
deleteTask(i) {
  const messages = this.state.messages.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
  this.setState({ messages });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @selvio-perez 
I have some questions
-How does exactly works the filter function here?
-deleteTask(i) {
  const messages = this.state.messages.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
  this.setState({ messages });
}
What does _ exactly do in the function?

Comment: The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Syntax:
let newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index, [array]])[, thisArg])

Comment: Thank you @selvio-perez I understand now better

And what it is _ in the filter method? I don´t see this point very clear

Comment: The filter callback receives 4 parameters, the first one is the current element being processed in the array, the second one is the index of the current element, so I use the _ in order to be able to access the second parameter of the function. You can check how filter method works here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter